# How to list audio devices with NAudio in a console app?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, naudio, .net-7.0

I want to list output audio devices in a .NET Core 7 Console app, that works on both Windows and Linux.

I've added NAudio via nuget, but it's missing the WaveOut class, which I would normally use for this task.  However, it appears that WaveOut class is in the NAudio.WinForms library, so that won't work, since it's tied to Windows (and specifically to WinForms).

I asked ChatGPT about cross-platform and it suggested using NAudio.Alsa for Linux.  I think, it's hallucinating, since I don't see anything like that.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. Can I list audio output devices in a console app (even if it's just Windows)?  If so, how?
2. Is it possible to use NAudio library with Linux?  Is there a separate library that I must use?